# Is it possible to make different approval processes work simultaneously with the help of sub-cases

Tags: case, approval-process, related-list

I have a requirement where I have to run multiple approval processes on the case level at the same time. Since Salesforce does not provide that option, hence I am thinking to create sub-cases and then run approval process under each of those.

This is what I want to do:

There are multiple checkboxes A,B,C on parent case. What I want is that when user selects Checkbox A then a subcase gets created with the appropriate name and an approval process within that sub-case.

Again, if user selects B checkbox on parent case, another sub-case gets created with the appropriate name and an approval process within that sub-case.

I am trying to write a process builder that looks if the checkbox is checked or not in the criteria, once the criteria matches it should create a sub-case and approval process under it. However, I don't know how to grab parent case id in order to create a sub-case under the relevant parent case.

Please help. Also, let me know if there is an alternate way to achieve the overall functionality.

Thanks